# Invoking a custom Timer Class

Tags: xcode, function, swift, nstimer, invoke

I've cobbled together a Timer class to use NSTimer with all my ViewControllers, the code is below

```
import Foundation

class Timer {
   var timer = NSTimer()
   var handler: (Int) -> ()

   let duration: Int
   var elapsedTime: Int = 0

   init(duration: Int, handler: (Int) -> ()) {
      self.duration = duration
      self.handler = handler
   }

   func start() {
      self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(30,
          target: self,
          selector: Selector("chkProgress"),
          userInfo: nil,
          repeats: true)
   }

   func stop() {
      timer.invalidate()
   }

   @objc func chkProgress() {
      self.elapsedTime++

      self.handler(elapsedTime)

      if self.elapsedTime == self.duration {
          self.stop()
      }
   }

   deinit {
      self.timer.invalidate()
   }
}
```

Then in each ViewController i can check the time progress and then display a message accordingly. The problem is when I try to invoke it

I've tried

```
var timer = Timer()
var timer = Timer(30)
var timer = Timer(30,30)
```

The resulting message is always the same telling me I cannot invoke Timer with type (int,int) which is how duration() in init is set out

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Your `init` method takes a *duration* and a *handler*, so you should call it with matching arguments ...

Comment: Looks great; feel free to use mine, though! https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk1ch12p499timerLeaker2/ch12p325NotificationLeaker/CancelableTimer.swift Has certain advantages you might like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters do not take an int, int. They take an int, and a closure.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html

You need to fix your Timer code as well;

```
class Timer {
    var timer = NSTimer()
    var handler: (x:Int) -> ()

    let duration: Int
    var elapsedTime: Int = 0

    init(duration: Int, handler: (Int) -> ()) {
        self.duration = duration
        self.handler = handler
    }

    func start() {
        self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(30,
            target: self,
            selector: Selector("chkProgress"),
            userInfo: nil,
            repeats: true)
    }

    func stop() {
        timer.invalidate()
    }

    @objc func chkProgress() {
        self.elapsedTime++

        self.handler(x: elapsedTime)

        if self.elapsedTime == self.duration {
            self.stop()
        }
    }

    deinit {
        self.timer.invalidate()
    }
}
```

//Implementation of Timer

```
var t = Timer(duration: 30, handler:{ (x:Int) -> Void in
            //Do soemthing with x;
        });
```